# How to write the same function with same name that handles different class arguments almost similarly in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, overloading

I have two different classes

```
class A_class {
public:
    string member_to_add_to;
}
```

and

```
class B_class {
    string member_to_add_to;
}
```

They both are almost similar with a slight difference in member variables. There is no inheritance involved. They both are used in different sections that do not merge together. I know it is not a good design but we don't have time to fix it now as the code base is large.

Then there is the `Modifier` class that takes a reference to an object of either `A_class` or `B_class` and makes some modifications to the class objects.

```
class Modifier() {
  method1(A_class& object_ or B_class& object);
  method2(A_class& object_ or B_class& object);
}
```

I need to write a function called `doSomething()` inside the `Modifier` class that takes in an object that is either `A_class` or `B_class` along with a string parameter that sets a member variable `member_to_add_to` to the string parameter and calls other methods within `Modifier`. Exactly only two lines differ based on they type of object being fed into this function.

```
void doSomething(A_class (or) B_class object_to_modify, string member_value) {
  object_to_modify.member_to_add_to = member_value;
  // after this 5 to 10 steps that call other methods taking a reference to object_to_modify but do the same thing
  method1(object_to_modify);
  method2(object_to_modify);
  //etc.,
}
```

Apart from the fact that it involves these two classes, everything else inside this function is the same exact code.
Should I just use function overloading for both the objects separately and replicate the code inside it twice in 2 functions except for the lines that differ?

Is there a more optimized/readable way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a template function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    char const* data;
};

struct B {
    char const* data;
};

template <typename T, 
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, A> || std::is_same_v<T, B>, int> = 0
>
void doSomething(T const& arg) {
    std::cout << arg.data << '\n';
}

int main() {
    A a{"Hello "};
    B b{"World"};
    foo(a);
    foo(b);
    // foo("something else"); // Doesn't compile
}
```

---

Slightly less cluttered with C++20 concepts:

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
void doSomething(T const& arg) requires (std::same_as<T, A> || std::same_as<T, B>) {
    std::cout << arg.data << '\n';
}
```

---

You could even over-engineer such a concept into your code-base if this is a common issue you have:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Types>
concept one_of = (std::same_as<T, Types> || ...);

template <one_of<A, B> T>
void doSomething(T const& arg) {
    std::cout << arg.data << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use template:

```
template <typename AorB>
void doSomething(AorB& object_to_modify, string member_value) {
  object_to_modify.member_to_add_to = member_value;
  // after this 5 to 10 steps that call other methods taking a reference to object_to_modify but do the same thing
  method1(object_to_modify);
  method2(object_to_modify);
  //etc.,
}
```